# UIButton Image being distorted in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UIButton in each tableviewcell that I have an image in. Basically I set the image to something different based on another parameter. You can ignore the totalTime/activityTimeInt stuff, but if it helps, they are just ints ( say totaltime = 60, activitytime = 50).  The following is the cellforrowatindexpath:

```
    if(totalTime <= activityTimeInt){
        [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicRed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5,13,70,70)];
    }
    if(totalTime + 10 >= activityTimeInt){
        [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicYellow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5,13,70,70)];
    }
    if(totalTime >=  activityTimeInt){
        [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicGreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5,13,70,70)];
    }
}
else if (!totalTime){
            [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicGreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5,13,70,70)];
}
return cell;
```

For some reason when the if statement runs through

```
else if (!totalTime){
            [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicGreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5,13,70,70)];
}
```

where totalTime doesn't exist, the images look like: [image: without totalTime if statement]

and when it runs through the other 3 if statements (with totalTime), they look like: [image: with totaltime ifstatements]

If you need more info just ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there something else in these if/else blocks that you haven't posted related to the label displaying 50 mins etc.?

Comment: No, there is nothing inside the if/else blocks except what is posted above. As for setting the labels the code is `cell.travelTimeLabel.text = [totalEverythingTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` but I don't think that affects the uibuttons

Comment: Is there any other field in the cell which gets a value when totaltime is nil vs otherwise? Basically, there has to be some other place in your code where these conditions are used again or totaltime is used again to set some field value.

Comment: No, in the entire cellforrowatindexpath method there is only that one if/else block using totaltime. Do you want to see the entire method?

Comment: Ok. You can post the method. Also, if this is a custom UITableViewCell, post its code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use this code

```
[cell.vicinitimeGraphicButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"travelDistanceGraphicRed.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

since

1. [`setImage:forState`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage%3aforState%3a): sets the image as the actual content of the button. For example, you can not see the button *title* even though you set it, because you have set an image as the content or else you can see both **image on left and text on right** which is in you case
2. [`setBackgroundImage:forState`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage%3aforState%3a): sets the image as the background. In this case, you can set the *title* and it is displayed on top of the image.

**Note that you are not setting default Background Image to you Button**

Comment: If I use setBackgroundImage, the images don't change after I run through the method again. The tableview changes based on a search and after you search again, the setBackgroundImage doesn't display the image at the front, which is why i used setImage

Comment: correct me if I am getting you wrong some times setBackgroundimage works and sometime it dosnt works is this what you mean.

Comment: sorry, no I mean that when I use setBackgroundImage, the first time I load the tableview it works fine, but when I try to update the tableview with new uibutton images using setbackgroundimage, the new updated image gets hidden behind the old image. Therefore only the  uibutton image loaded when I load the tableview first is displayed. I may be wrong with this but when I use setImage the images seem to be updating.

Comment: So you have issue while updating table View.

Comment: the tableview updates fine with the new images loading if I use setImage, except the images are distorted like i said in the question

Comment: @Spenciefy you said that updating cell with new image is causing a problem when you use SetBackgroundImage

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was that I had set the default image in the customtablecell.xib file, when I shouldn't have. fail on my part. however, it should be setbackgroundimage like ayush said above.

[image]

the default image shouldn't be set to anything.